# jpegcam, disable capture button after deny access

Tags: flash, webcam

In my php project i have used jpegcam, http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/   &  When we are loading web cam capture page its asking for flash player permissions "allow or deny", even if i denied the option capture button is enabled.I want to disable capture button when it loads & enable only if the user allows the permissions!

So how to check that user has allowed or denied webcam access in privacy settings dialog box to the site?
! Guys, any help would be appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript's `Camera.muted` property is what you need. The source you linked to creates a private `Camera` object named `camera`. You can make it public or add a new method to check its `muted` property;

```
final public function has_access( ) : Boolean {
    return !camera.muted;
}
```

Typically you would hide/disable the button *until* muted becomes false (it's very unlikely it will become true again; the user would have to manually open the settings box and disable access).

You can also use a listener to avoid constantly checking this value;

```
final public function add_access_listener( myFunc : Function ) : void {
    camera.addEventListener( "status", myFunc ); // StatusEvent.STATUS
}
```

Which would be used like this:

```
myWebcam.add_access_listener( myAccessFunc );
function myAccessFunc( ev : StatusEvent ) : void {
    if( ev.code == "Camera.Unmuted" ) {
        // video became available, enable button
    } else {
        // video became unavailable, disable button
    }
}
// remember that the user could have granted persistent permission
// (i.e. the status will be unmuted without actually changing)
if( myWebcam.has_access( ) ) {
    // video is already available, enable button
} else {
    // video is not yet available, disable button
}
```

To avoid any possible memory leaks, you should also also call `removeEventListener` if you ever remove the camera, but the library doesn't seem to be designed to do that anyway (and doesn't remove its own listeners).